# Assign same value to multiple elements of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

Is possible to **assign same value to multiple elements of array** in JavaScript ?

If i have this array:

```
  var arr= [
   [0,1],
   [0,1],
   [0,1]
  ];
```

Is possible to assign value `1` to `arr[i][0]` for all elements having like output:

```
  [
   [1,1],
   [1,1],
   [1,1],
   [1,1]
  ]
```

This output without to use **for loop**?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is this homework?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far? Please show your attempt so that we can help you.

Comment: How do you want to update each location without accessing each location?

Comment: This smells like homework.  Please explain why you don't want to use a `for` loop so we can better understand the actual problem here.  Heck, you can just use `.forEach()` if you need to iterate over the array without actually using the `for` keyword, but ALL methods of setting multiple elements of the array will involve a loop somewhere which is why these questions always seem kind of stupid without some context as to why.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of achieving this without a `for` loop, however, [`Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) is probably easiest and modifies the array in place.

```
arr.fill([1,1])
```

Other methods like [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) will return a new array.

Comment: This doesn't modify just the first element of the nested arrays, it resets the entire contents of each nested array.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree, the scope for this is limited, but I'm basing it off the OP's examples where all items in source and result are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function

```
arr = arr.map(x => [1, x[1]])
```

Comment: Its not a for loop. I don't know how else it could be done, there has to be some iteration of the elements. I do agree that it is a bit strange

Comment: @Sam The question specifically said `for` loop, which isn't the same thing as an iterator function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` for this as well

```js
var res = [
   [0,1],
   [0,1],
   [0,1]
].map(([d, ...rest]) => [1, ...rest])

console.log(res)
```